# Encoding an array of hashes in Perl

Tags: json, perl, hash

I'm trying to do something that seems to be very simple, but I can't figure out how to do it in Perl : I want to output a JSON-formatted array of hashes.

The array of hashes in question is actually an array of `DBIx::MyParse Item`s object instances. Here is my code :

```
use strict;
use DBIx::MyParse;
use JSON::PP;
my $json = JSON::PP->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;

our $parser = DBIx::MyParse->new( database => "test", datadir => "/tmp/myparse" );
our $query = $parser->parse("UPDATE table1 SET field1 = 1;");

$json->convert_blessed(1);
print $json->encode(@{$query} );
```

And this is what this script outputs :

```
"SQLCOM_UPDATE"
```

Which is actually the first element of the array that I want to output as a whole. Here is the content of the array that I see when I step-by-step debug the script :
[image: Query debug value]

I would like to have the whole structure in my JSON output. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 5):

`JSON::encode` just expects a single argument, not a list. Use `$json->encode( $query )`.